# Question on the given proof of $(\det A)(\det B) \leq [(\operatorname{tr} AB)/n]^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

I was reading through [this paper](http://willkwon.dothome.co.kr/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/20180822.pdf) and on page 6, there is a lemma proving $(\det A)(\det B) \leq [(\operatorname{tr} AB)/n]^n$ for two positive semideifinite matrices $A$ and $B$.

I get every single line until the part that concluded $\operatorname{tr} AB = \sum \lambda_l \mu_l $. Especially, what's bugging me is the very last equation. Before the equality sign we have
$$ \sum S_{li} (S^T)_{il} (D_1)_{ii} (D_2)_{ll} $$
and after the equality sign we have
$$ \sum \delta^{il} (D_1)_{ii} (D_2)_{ll} $$
Since S is a symmetric orthonormal matrix, $\ S_{li} = (S^T)_{il}$, so I believe the first term should just be $ s^2_{li} (D_1)_{ii} (D_2)_{ll} $. But it doesn't make sense that $ s^2_{li} = \delta^{il} $, since the orthonormal matrix just confirms that the 2-norm of any 'row' or 'column' is 1, not that the single $ s^2_{li} $ is $1$ for $l=i$ and $0$ otherwise.

There must be something I am missing. Can anyone help me filling the gap between those two line, please?

P.S. The paper is about elliptic equation, but the lemma is for general positive semidefinite matrices, so I put tag just for these type of questions.

Comment: An orthonormal matrix has the defining property that $$\mathbf{SS^T = I}$$ which is that delta.

Comment: @NinadMunshi You are right, but that delta is what we get 'after' summing up with either $i$ or $l$ variable. However, because we have $ (D_1)_{ii} (D_2)_{ll} $ multiplied, we cannot get the Kronecker's delta right away, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S=R^TQ$ is orthogonal, not symmetric as they claimed, but that is inconsequential to the proof.

Anyway, it is not true that $\operatorname{tr}(SD_1S^TD_2)=\operatorname{tr}(D_1D_2)$.  For example,
$D_1=\operatorname{diag}(1,2)=D_2$, and $S=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.  Then $SD_1S^T=\operatorname{diag}(2,1)$ and so we end up with $4$ on LHS and $5$ on RHS.

A much easier proof of the result they want is simply to use $\sqrt{A}B\sqrt{A}$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, has determinant $\det A\det B$ and trace $\operatorname{tr}AB$.  The result follows from AM-GM on its eigenvalues.

Comment: How do you say, $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ symmetric, because,, whether $A,B$ are symmetric or not,,,not given.

Comment: @Subhajit It is given $A,B$ are symmetric psd

Comment: it's only given, psd,,not symmetric,,and non-symmetric matrix can be psd.

Comment: @Subhajit Not the convention in the paper linked, see end of page 3.

Comment: Hmmm, ok,,I didn't notice the paper first.

Comment: God I was fooled into thinking that $S$ is symmetric. Plus, your three line proof is amazing. Thanks for your help!